# How to recreate dSYMs

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, dsym

We have an app which was uploaded to the app store but we lost the dSYMs before uploading them to get symbolicated. Is there a way to recreate the dSYMs from a previous build?

I'm not looking to download them. I'm in need of recreating them from only having the original source code.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the Xcode Organizer: From the Xcode menu, select Window > Organizer > Archives > (select a mobile app).
2. From Version, select the archive that matches the app version (listed first) and build number (following the app version in parentheses).
3. Select Download dSYMs.

The dSYMs will be downloaded from Apple if available and if the file names contain a series of letters and numbers. If the dSYM files are named after the the dependencies in your project, the download will not be successful.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Dg5.png)

Comment: This should work, and if it doesn't you can also download dSYMs via iTunes Connect. Check out this doc for more on both methods: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#downloading-bitcode-dsyms

Comment: That didn't work, it says there are no dSYMs available to download. I'm looking if there is a way to recreate them. Maybe submitting a new build is the best option.